# Работа с radiobutton и созднием элементов с плейсхолдером

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой калькулятор serjo96.github.io/matrix
Необходимо добавить функционал добавления и удаления строк,столбцов при выбранных радиобаттонах при том что еще должен добавляться плейсхолдер с продолжение отчета (см. ссылку).
Как я понимаю для начала надо добавить проверку radio

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var rad=document.getElementsByName('mtrx_sel');
    for (var i=0;i<rad.length; i++) {
      if (rad[i].checked) {
        alert('Выбран '+i+' radiobutton');
      }
    }

});
```

ну а затем в if уже писать обработчик клика?может кто подкинуть примерный код или подсказать как такие вещи вообще реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого вот код который мне нужен был)

```js
$('.add_str').click(function(){
  if ($("#check_mtrx_a").prop("checked")){
    $('.matrix_a tr:first').clone().appendTo('.matrix_a'); 
  }else if($("#check_mtrx_b").prop("checked")) {
    $('.matrix_b tr:first').clone().appendTo('.matrix_b'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам необходимо повесить обработчик событий на элементы. Вот как пример.

```
var controls = document.querySelector('.add_mtrx');
controls.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e) {
  var nodeName = e.target.nodeName;

  if (nodeName == 'BUTTON' || nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    console.log("Кликнули на ", e.target);
  }

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zYo7u0yHOh7BsGYiygxH?p=preview

Comment: Абсолютно верно,огромное спасибо)

Comment: Но необходимо учитывать еще и выбранный radio button.По логике должно выходить что при выбранном radio и после нажатия на кнопку добавления добавляется строка или столбец для одной из матриц.

Comment: Так проверку на checked добавьте у нужного радиобатона.

Comment: ммммм,т.е когда выбираешь радио,он ставит атрибут чекед и его можно кок раз проверить через if?

Comment: Да, естественно аттрибут checked у чекбокса ставится в true при клике, только я не понимаю зачем его проверять если итак уже известно по какому элементу кликнули. В общем в данной ситуации есть два подхода или вешать обработчик на click или на change у checkbox.

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял то при клике он не поймет какой checkbox выбран,по этому стоит брать change на чек а затем вызывать эту функцию при клике на добавление или удаление?